# Access heart rate variability wear os app

Tags: android, wear-os, health-monitoring

I'm developing a stress detection wear os application for my master and need to access the heart rate variability (HRV), preferably I would like to avoid solutions where I have to depend on other applications, but rather just get the raw HRV. I am currently available to get the heart rate.

What I've tried so far:

- I've read that HRV is accessible through health connect, which is (as I understand) a way for android users to share their data with 3rd party applications. However, this makes my application  dependent on health connect, and also removes the possibility for me to do "live" analysis, as I need to first read the HRV from health connect.
- I have also read that HRV is accessible through Android Privileged Health SDK, which requires quite a lot for mye to apply for, as a university student who only needs the SDK for a proof-of-concept type of app.

After searching through documentations I have not been able to find a solution.
Is there any other way for me to access HRV?

Edit: does anyone know if reading from health connect may be sufficient / fast enough for live analysis?

Comment: I don't think that's possible with Health Services, I was thinking you could calculate HRV yourself, but it's impossible to get the time between heart beats, only option is use Fitbit API or Samsung health API

Comment: Health Connect is not fast enough for live analysis as there are no guarantees for how frequently another app will write HRV to Health Connect.

Comment: @Breana do you know if it is possible to get HRV through health services?

Comment: As of today, HRV is not supported through Health Services

Comment: We waited quite a while to get the privileged health sdk and in the meantime tried to get the IBI values (inter-beat-intervall) - we couldn't find a way. So unfortunately it might not be possible.